# OpenAM protecting REST resources, require consideration of Media-Type as well as HTTP Action

Tags: rest, authorization, openam, media-type

When writing authorization policies for OpenAM then Actions (GET,POST, etc.) can be specified for a REST resource, but can the Media-Type also be used to set the boundaries of a policy, e.g. if I have one update end point that takes 2 different command bodies distinguished by Media-Type:

1. POST /someresource "application/vnd.**update1**+json"
2. POST /someresource "application/vnd.**update2**+json"

How could I write a policy for OpenAM that distinguished these cases and applied different authorization profiles to each??

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to write a custom policy plugin to make decisions based on media type.

Another option would be to use something like OpenIG, and perform filtering on the request.